# Does reusing a DB connection with EF 6 DbContexts save time?

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

My code is littered with `using` blocks that instantiate, use, and dispose a `DbContext` object. Would it improve performance any if I passed an open connection to the constructors of these objects, or does connection pooling do enough work for me on that front?

Comment: If you're using that many contexts you are misusing EF anyway. Normally, you should have one context per request and share the entire object model for everything the request does.

Comment: Although not 'per request', I only use one `DbContext` per query, and it must open it's own, or a pooled, or if no pooling, a shared, connection. This happens often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would depend on the database system you address, and wheter the ADO.NET provider supports conection pooling for that particular database system.

Answer to your question: For SQL Server, no, but for SQL Server Compact, yes.

Comment: You can't be asserting that ADO.NET doesn't support connection pooling for SQL Server? I must somehow be misunderstanding you.

Comment: I was answering your question, answer clarified/updated.

Answer (score 1):

If your provider supports it, connection pooling handles this well enough in my experience. If you think it's a bottleneck you should of course benchmark.

In a similar line of thinking, I once created a class like this:

```
class Foo
{
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd1, cmd2;

    void DoStuff();

    static Foo GetFoo() { get from cache, or create a new one. }
}
```

Rather than construct a new one every request, I kept the connections open and commands ready for action, caching the entire `Foo` object. This, disappointingly, was only *very* marginally more performant with SQL Server.

In your case there's the whole other layer of Entity Framework, so your overall improvement is going to be even less significant. In general I assume that if you're using EF you don't have a requirement for massive performance in the first place so the added complexity for such a small gain is probably not worth it.